# c++ cannot print escape character

Tags: c++, linux

I am trying to write a program that interacts with some instruments that require commands beginning with the escape character (ascii 27) but am having trouble testing as the program seems to hang the moment it attempts to print the escape character. This program is compiled with g++ in an Ubuntu machine and run from gnome-terminal:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <limits>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string str;
    const int numSamples=10;
    const int escapeInt = 27;
    const char escapeChar = escapeInt;

//    sleep(30);
    //Ask for the latest test results
    cin.clear();
//    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max());
    cout << "\n\n\n";
    cout << escapeChar << "PF2 -" << numSamples;
    cerr << "\n\n\n" << escapeChar << "PF2 -" << numSamples;
//    cin.ignore(2,'\n');
    getline( cin, str, '\n');
    cerr << str;

    int k=1;
    while (k<=numSamples)//getline(cin, str))
    {
        getline( cin, str, '\n');
        k++;
        cerr << str << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The output is just three blank lines and then the program becomes unresponsive. It doesn't even respond to ctrl-c. Any suggestions as to how to get around this?

Comment: You're sending your output (including the escape character) to `cout`, which sounds like it's your terminal (since you say you see the three blank lines). How do you intend the instrument commands to actually get to the instrument?

Comment: Are you sure the data stream is being directed to the right place in time? One obvious explanation would be if the terminal (or some Linux service) were getting confused by the escape sequence.

Comment: I use cout because I will be using socat (if you're familiar with it) to connect the stdout of this program to a telnet session over tcp/ip. I did a dummy run of this just connecting two socat sessions, running stdio from one session to the stdio of the program in another. This resulted in the output side of the program session (prints stderr to screen) freezing while the other session completed and exited successfully.

Comment: Try to not output the escape sequence to `cerr` (your terminal). Also be aware that often the escape needed is like `"\0x1b[" or the like, that is, with a square bracket added. I don't recall exactly from thirty years back.

Comment: Alright. I'll substitute "[ESC]" in for the cerr output and see if the other escape character makes it through to the real instrument. I'm fairly certain the square bracket isn't necessary in this case based on the documentation of the instrument I'm interfacing with. 0x1b is the same as my ascii 27 char so the effect there should be the same (I think).

Comment: You're probably better off piping to `socat` directly through your code instead of writing to `std::cout` and piping via your shell.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune I'm not sure how I would achieve that. Can you expand?

Answer (score -1):

Oh, I *can* answer my own question. As was suggested by @Alf, (Thank you) it seems that I just shouldn't be trying to print the escape sequence to cerr as that winds up being interpreted by my terminal which, in my case with gnome-terminal, is a no-no.

Thanks for the useful insight folks!